# echo without trimming the space in awk command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file consisting of multiple rows like this

```
10|EQU000000001|12345678|3456||EOMCO042|EOMCO042|31DEC2018|16:51:17|31DEC2018|SHOP NO.5,6,7 RUNWAL GRCHEMBUR      MHIN|0000000010000.00|6761857316|508998|6011|GL
```

I have to split and replace the column 11 into 4 different columns using the count of character.

This is the 11th column containing extra spaces also.

```
SHOP NO.5,6,7 RUNWAL GRCHEMBUR      MHIN
```

This is I have done

```
ls *.txt *.TXT| while read line
do
subName="$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<<"$line")"
 awk -F"|"   '{ "echo  -n "$11" | cut -c1-23" | getline ton;
             "echo -n  "$11" | cut -c24-36" | getline city;
             "echo -n  "$11" | cut -c37-38" | getline state;
             "echo -n  "$11" | cut -c39-40" | getline country;
$11=ton"|"city"|"state"|"country; print $0

}' OFS="|" $line > $subName$output
```

done

But while doing echo of 11th column, its trimming the extra spaces which leads to mismatch in count of character. Is there any way to echo without trimming spaces ?

Actual output

```
10|EQU000000001|12345678|3456||EOMCO042|EOMCO042|31DEC2018|16:51:17|31DEC2018|SHOP NO.5,6,7 RUNWAL GR|CHEMBUR MHIN|||0000000010000.00|6761857316|508998|6011|GL
```

Expected Output

```
10|EQU000000001|12345678|3456||EOMCO042|EOMCO042|31DEC2018|16:51:17|31DEC2018|SHOP NO.5,6,7 RUNWAL GR|CHEMBUR|MH|IN|0000000010000.00|6761857316|508998|6011|GL
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186096/discussion-on-question-by-muddassir-rahman-echo-without-trimming-the-space-in-aw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure-bash implementation of all this logic

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nocaseglob extglob
for f in *.txt; do
  subName=${f%.*}
  while IFS='|' read -r -a fields; do
    location=${fields[10]}
    ton=${location:0:23}; ton=${ton%%+([[:space:]])}
    city=${location:23:12}; city=${city%%+([[:space:]])}
    state=${location:36:2}
    country=${location:38:2}
    fields[10]="$ton|$city|$state|$country"
    printf -v out '%s|' "${fields[@]}"
    printf '%s\n' "${out:0:$(( ${#out} - 1 ))}"
  done <"$f" >"$subName.out"
done
```

It's slower (if I did this well, by about a factor of 10) than *pure* awk would be, but much faster than the awk/shell combination proposed in the question.

---

Going into the constructs used:

- All the `${varname%...}` and related constructs are [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). The specific `${varname%pattern}` construct removes the shortest possible match for `pattern` from the value in `varname`, or the longest match if `%` is replaced with `%%`.
- Using `extglob` enables extended globbing syntax, such as `+([[:space:]])`, which is equivalent to the regex syntax `[[:space:]]+`.

Answer (score 4):

The least annoying way to code this that I've found so far is:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[10] = join "|", unpack "a23 A13 a2 a2", $F[10]; print join "|", @F'
```

It's fairly straightforward:

- Iterate over lines of input; split each line on `|` and put the fields in `@F`.
- For the 11th field (`$F[10]`), split it into fixed-width subfields using `unpack` (and trim trailing spaces from the second field (`A` instead of `a`)).
- Reassemble subfields by joining with `|`.
- Reassemble the whole line by joining with `|` and printing it.

I haven't benchmarked it in any way, but it's likely much faster than the original code that spawns multiple shell and cut processes per input line because it's all done in one process.

A complete solution would wrap it in a shell loop:

```
for file in *.txt *.TXT; do
    outfile="${file%.*}$output"
    perl -F'\|' -lane '...' "$file" > "$outfile"
done
```

Or if you don't need to trim the `.txt` part (and you don't have too many files to fit on the command line):

```
perl -i.out -F'\|' -lane '...' *.txt *.TXT
```

This simply places the output for each input file `foo.txt` in `foo.txt.out`.